# How to create a drop down from API JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie to Webapi with `AngularJS`. I have a URL which will give data in `JSON` format, I need to catch only employeename from the given data and pit it in drop down list in `AngularJS`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proper way to do it is using the [**ng-options** directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). The HTML would look like this.

```
<select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" 
        ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in testAccounts">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
    $scope.testAccounts = [];

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/your-api-url',
        }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.testAccounts = result;
    });
});
```

You'll also need to be sure that angular is run on your HTML and that your module is loaded.

```
<html ng-app="test">
    <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    ....
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $filter to filter out data from the Json array like below,

$filter('filter')(your json array, { column name: value}, true)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `<select name="{{option.empname}}" ng-model="modelName" ng-options="option for option in empdetail"> 
</select>`

For more detail, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570134/dynamic-select-list-default-selected-item-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this simple full qualified **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymm0ae55/)**.

#### View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" 
          ng-options="option.name for option in options"></select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.options = [];
    $scope.selected = null;

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    }).then(function (result) {
      $scope.options = result.data;
      $scope.selected = $scope.options[0];
    });;
});
```